# Comparing NodeJS and Java

Tags: java, node.js

So here is my node js http servers in A SINGLE program file, It's  important that I am not running below 2 servers in 2 separate processes. 
They are running in same process.

```
var today = require('./today');
var http = require('http');

var server1 = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var now = Date.now();
    var body = "The day of the week is " + today() + " " + now;
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': body.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end(body);
});

server1.listen(3000);


var server2 = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var body = "The day of the week is " + today();
    var count = 0;
    while (true) {
        count++;
        if(count == 10000){
            console.log('server2');
            count = 0;
        }
    }   
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': body.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end(body);
});

server2.listen(3002);
```

After running this node js program I sent requests to server1 it worked i.e I got good response. (200)

So then I sent request for server2 it went into infinite loop and this second request hanged obviously.

While second request is hanging I send 3rd request to server1 at port 3000 the server1 hanged as well so it means
nodejs does not support concurrent requests processing i.e when a specific request is getting processed by callback handler no other requests
can process even though my machine is intel i7 multi core...that infinite loop in server2 should only block one of the cores,
remaining core should have processed subsequent requests on server1.

#

So below is a java web service deployed in glassfish, I developed it as stateless EJB so that the ejb container can create multiple instances
of this EJB and process multiple requests on this web service simultaneously

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
@Stateless()
public class NewWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        if(txt.equals("infinite")){
            int i = 0;
            while(true){
                i++;
                if(i>10000){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        i=0;
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "Hello " + txt + " !" + (new Date());
    }
}
```

When I deployed above web service in glassfish and sent request with "infinite" as input then that request hanged BUT from another browser window I sent another request to same web service with "Aziz" as input  it returned good result at same time when the window with "infinite" input was hanging ... BUT WHEN I COMMENTED THE Thread.sleep(2000); IN ABOVE THEN BOTH REQUESTS HANG SO IT MEANS JAVA DOES NOT SUPPORT CONCURRENT REQUETS EITHER.

Conclusion: java and node js behave in same manner at least for web servers I created, irrespective of the fact that nodejs has a notion of callback which it projects to be something magical... so my question is why are we particularly calling nodejs as single threaded, in this particular issue java is behaving in same manner.

Note: I am not talking about the nodejs async calls that u can make using async functions like crypto.pbkdf2sync crypto.pbkdf2.#############################

**Updated after @minus's first update**:
Thanks a lot @minus, you said:
"If 99% of your response time is due to IO, nodejs will just work fine, even better then the multi-threaded environment of java."

So I changed my node code, I changed the infinite call to read a file which is mostly IO based operation, still server2 blocked the server1. If we compare node's behavior with java's then java is concurrently processing where as node is getting blocked on a long running callback...it does not matter if that callback is mostly doing IO or not. Below is my changed node code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server1 = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var now = Date.now();
    var body = "Time " + now;
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': body.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end(body);
});

server1.listen(3000);

var fs = require('fs');

var server2 = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    while (true) {
        fs.readFile('stuff.txt', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
            }else{
               console.log(contents);
            }
        }); 

        var contents = fs.readFileSync('stuff.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(contents);
    }

    var now = Date.now();
    var body = "Time " + now;

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': body.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.end(body);
});

server2.listen(3002);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your exact test but I can do a similar test with minimal configuration in Java.

I use maven to manage dependencies.

This is a minimal pom to run the example.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.minus</groupId>
    <artifactId>thread.demo.ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jersey.version>2.29</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the class which runs the server:

```
package thread.demo.ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String BASE_URI = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/ws/";
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("thread.demo.ws");
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(new URI(BASE_URI), rc, false);
        try {
            server.start();
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            server.shutdownNow();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a the resource:

```
package thread.demo.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("echo")
public class Echo {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String get(@QueryParam("msg") String echoMsg) {
        if("LOCK".equalsIgnoreCase(echoMsg)) {
            while(true) {
            }
        }
        String reply = echoMsg == null ? "PING" : echoMsg;
        return " - " + reply + " - ";
    }
}
```

The request which will trigger the service is :

```
http://localhost:3000/ws/echo?msg=hello
```

The request which will locks forever the tread is:

```
http://localhost:3000/ws/echo?msg=LOCK
```

You can test this and you will find that Java will keep processing request even if one (or more) thread replying to a request are stuck in an infinite loop.

Eventually you will lock too many thread and the system will not respond anymore.

Java is multi-threaded so you *can* process multiple requests at the same time.

The reason why your test does not provide the correct result may depend on many reasons, the most plausible is that by causing an infinite loop in a thread you will possibly prevent the graceful shutdown of your application server, possibly preventing also a correct redeploy of your application.

Java and node have 2 different approaches to deal with concurrent request, nodes opts using several *processes* each managing non blocking IO processing, while java (mainly) uses a single process running multiple threads, depending on many different factors one can perform better then the other.

There are also many application servers written in java which us NIO (non blocking IO) to reduce the number of thread used, so also in java you can use the same paradigm of Node.

### Update after comment

You are misusing nodejs by blocking in server1.

It is an useful experiment to understand how bad is blocking in any part of your code, but you should really never block in js.

Your server would be implemented more or less like this:

```
function(request, response) {
    request.json()
        .then(data=>callService(data))
        .catch(err=> sendError(err,response))
        .then(someEntity => buildResponseWithEntity(someEntity,response ) )
        .catch(e => logError(e));
}
```

where the body of your function would return immediately, while each step of your process (.then and .catch) would be eventually processed, each also never blocking to wait for any IO.

If 99% of your response time is due to IO, nodejs will just work fine, even better then the multi-threaded environment of java.

To explain this in any detail would require too much time.

Comment: Hi @minus, thanks for the answer, so your answer solves one issue, but raises another. I saw that due to infinite loop upon first deployment my with Thead.sleep(2000); kind of messed up my glassfish and when I deployed the second time with commented Thread.sleep(2000); the deployment did get messed up. I can see that java is responding upon subsequent requests after first request with "infinite" param so ok java server is multithreaded and nodejs is not multithreaded, thats one issue solved. But the issue arises is that if nodejs server2 blocks the server1 in my node code what good is nodejs?